# Mac: Can't convert to real path: Input/output error

Tags: macos, mount, nfs, automount, autofs

I am trying to automatically mount a NFS share on Mavericks. I have the /etc/auto_master and the /etc/auto.myserver files configured as I have on other Macs. I also have the symlinks in the root. Running the mount command manually works:

```
mount -t nfs myserver:/myshare /mnt
```

But when I boot the computer the shares are not mounted. If I run `automount -vc`, then I get:

```
root# automount -vc
automount: /net updated
automount: /myshare: Can't convert to real path: Input/output error
automount: /Network/Servers updated
automount: /myserver updated
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The rules for answering say "be sure to answer the question" and although I can't tell you how to fix your problem, I'll use your question "Am I missing something?" to submit this comment:

You're probably not missing something because something broke in Mavericks regarding mounts and I've been waiting and hoping they will fix it. I am NFS mounting a different way but perhaps the problems are related.

I have a longtime NFS mount of a Linux system's user directory onto my iMac using a Directory Utility entry with fields RecordType dsRecTypeStandard:Mounts, VFSLinkDir /Users/tux/linuxHome, VFSType nfs, etc.

This was working fine across 2 previous upgrades of MacOS and abruptly stopped working when I upgraded to Mavericks.  I don't know if it's just NFS mounts with Directory Utility or DU mounts in general.